# Why does my ImageView not fill the whole screen using scaleType=fitXY?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm having trouble understanding my `ImageView` does not scale to fill the entirety of the screen.

There seems to be some white space along the sides.

Here is what I mean:
[image]

My .xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.Activity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/coupon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I not understanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all of those padings :

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Your `RelativeLayout` should be like :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.Activity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/coupon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set padding for your RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines and try it out

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Because you have set the padding for parent layout i.e Relative Layout. so remove all those padding's
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```